# ATL CComPtr copy constructor

Tags: com

I use on my COM server simple object constructor:

```
CComPtr<IObj>      obj; //member
 hr = SUCCEDDED(hr) ? this->obj.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CObj)) : hr;

STDMETHODIMP CConfig::get_Obj(IObj ** pVal)
{
    if (pVal == nullptr)
    {
        return E_POINTER;
    }

    CComPtr<IObj> result(this->obj);
    *pVal = result.Detach();
    return S_OK;
}
```

What I want to accomplish is for the get_Obj() method to return same interface object at succesive calls. Looking over the code CComPtr seems to increment reference count. I also detach afterwards from CComPtr. 
Is this the right way to implement what I want ? I don't want the COM client to be forced to "dispose" the IObj interface object every time it calls method get_Obj().

Comment: Use the CComPtr::CopyTo() method.

Comment: Hans Passant: It would have exactly the same effect plus two extra  useless `AddRef()`/`Release()` calls.

Comment: Erm, no, check CComPtrBase::CopyTo() in vc/atlmfc/include/atlcomcli.h.  There's only one AddRef call there.

Comment: @Hans Passant: In the OP code there's an `AddRef()` inside `CComPtr` constructor already. If you call `CopyTo()` that's a second `AddRef()`, then `CComPtr` still sharing ownership is destroyed and calls `Release()`. In the OP code there's only `AddRef()` in the constructor, so it's a bit faster and not that less clear.

Comment: I meant to replace it with obj.CopyTo(*pVal) of course.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I see, yes, that would be equivalent to what the OP does and more elegant, but he would need to return the `HRESULT` that `CopyTo()` returns - it will become a one-liner. I believe it would be a good separate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you implement it in one of the clearest ways. You'd have to store the last returned value somewhere - for example in `CConfig` as a member variable. Other than that you can't provide clean onwership semantics - it's normal that the client will expect the returned pointer to be `AddRef()`ed (as in your code) and it's normal that the client will release the object ownership. If you want to return the same object you have to store an extra pointer somewhere and that pointer must also own the object (call `AddRef()` at least once).

So your code does it right - it copies a stored pointer and does `AddRef()`. You could just as well go without `CComPtr`:

```
if (pVal == nullptr) {
    return E_POINTER;
}

*pVal = this->obj;
if( this->obj != 0 ) {
   this->obj->AddRef();
}
return S_OK;
```

Comment: So, in this case for the same object - this->obj we call "this->obj->AddRef()" for every client CConfig::get_Obj() method call. In this case we still require from the client code to "dispose" of it at every call isn't it ? Otherwise reference count for the obj does not decrease and when CConfig is destroyed it will not delete the obj (the ownership of obj is split between multiple clients calls and CConfig isn't it ?)

Comment: @Ghita: The client will have to call `Release()` once for each time he called `get_Obj()` - that's normal COM ownership transfer semantics in action. The caller and your object will be sharing ownership - that's normal too.